# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token error while parsing JSON

Tags: json, ajax

I am new to AJAX and It seems like I might be missing a quite fundamental detail.

I am trying to debug server side while processing AJAX request. The code works fine with the following line commented out at the server side.

```
//  php_console ($inputName, '  -  Field EMPTY!!!');
```

When the above line executed it gives 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token' error while parsing the JSON data at the AJAX success function, at the following line

```
var valResponse = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
```

It seems like AJAX return variable 'theResponse' is the same either way, at least visually when I print it.

```
$("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
```

Why echo'ing out anything cause parseJSON to break ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is AJAX request:

```
function performFormValidation(formID, fieldObject, action) {
    formFieldsData  = prepFormDataForAjax (formID);
    var URL      = BASE_DIR + 'formValidation.php'
    var formData = JSON.stringify(formFieldsData);

    $.ajax({
        url:    URL,
        type:   'POST',
        data:   {data:formData},
        success: function(theResponse){
            $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            var valResponse = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert ('Error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the AJAX process:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$response = array();

foreach ($data as $dataField) {
    $inputName = $dataField[0][0];
    $formEntry = trim($dataField[0][1]);

    $validData = 1;
    $errorCode = '';
    foreach ($dataField as $pair) {

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //  data-rule-required
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ($pair[0] == 'data-rule-required' && $pair[1] == 'true' && isEmpty($formEntry)) {
        //  php_console ($inputName, '  -  Field EMPTY!!!');
            $validData=0; $errorCode=sprintf( _('This field is requided'));
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

and here is the php_console function:

```
function php_console($data, $alert) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'console.log("' . $data . $alert .'")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All PHP echo statements (typically) go directly to the web service response -- regardless of where you put it. All echo statements are appended in the order of control flow of your code. What happens in your case is that the javascript script tag appears as a part of your JSON and breaks the syntax.

Look into the response tab in your browser to check the exact response -- you'll see it is not JSON and hence your error.